# Specify .eml file name using System.Net.Mail.MailAddress or other library

Tags: c#, vb.net

I need to file an email when requested.

**My code below works:**

- Sends email
- Files the email when requested
- But does not allow me to specify the file name (uses a guid as file name)
- **Example: c:\Archive\email\1003d05d-11ca-45e2-a5f4-cf2da29c39d9.eml**

**Potential Solutions:**

1. Save the file to a temporary folder, rename file, and then copy to final destination
2. Save the file using another method, better performance

**Pros and Cons**

- Solution 1: is ugly and has bad performance

**Question**

Does anyone know how to file an email to "MySpecifiedFileName.eml", without having to rename and then copy?

**Existing Code:**

```
Public Shared Sub Send(ByVal EmailFrom As String, ByVal EmailTo As String, ByVal Subject As String, ByVal HTMLBody As String, Optional SaveToFile As Boolean = False, Optional SaveFilepath As String = "")
    Dim MyMsg As MailMessage = New MailMessage

    Dim Recipients() As String
    Recipients = Split(EmailTo, ";")

    With MyMsg
        .From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(EmailFrom)
        For i = 0 To Recipients.Count - 1
            If Recipients(i).ToString <> "" Then
                .To.Add(New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(Recipients(i)))
            End If
        Next
        .Sender = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(EmailFrom)
        .Subject = Subject
        .Body = HTMLBody
        .BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
        .IsBodyHtml = True
        .Priority = MailPriority.High            
    End With

    Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient(My.Settings("SMTPServer"))
    SmtpServer.Send(MyMsg)

    REM
    REM Save Email when requested
    REM
    If SaveToFile = True Then
        Dim client As New SmtpClient(My.Settings("SMTPServer"))
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory
        client.PickupDirectoryLocation = SaveFilepath
        client.Send(MyMsg)
        client = Nothing
    End If
    MyMsg = Nothing
    SmtpServer = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264672/how-to-save-mailmessage-object-to-disk-as-eml-or-msg-file for one possible solution.  You can save it to a stream and then you can save the stream to the filename of your choice.

Comment: If this is going to be single-threaded (i.e., only one email being saved at any given time), you can save it to a temporary directory, and then rename and move the file to the permanent final destination.  If client.send returns the filename, you can just rename it.

Comment: You should also be [aware of difference in the `eml` file format](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6603002/231316). IIS saves files with this extension and Outlook reads files with this extension but there are differences.

Comment: Good to know. Do you have a link that I could read?

Comment: Not sure if you've seen [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32434/Adding-Save-functionality-to-Microsoft-Net-Mail-Ma) in your research, but it provides a save method (with filename) for the .Net Mail system.  Note that there is an update at the bottom of the code for Net 4.5.

Comment: Should @ChicagoMike post the core parts of the CodeProject article as an answer? Do you need extra help or are you satisfied with that solution?

Comment: I think the only way to win a bounty is to post the answer.

Yes I am satisfied with the answer.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Allan Eagle over at CodeProject.com has created an [extension of the System.Net.Mail.MailMessage class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32434/Adding-Save-functionality-to-Microsoft-Net-Mail-Ma) that includes the ability to save an email with a specific file name.  I believe this will address the issue you raised.